# On demand feature view using multiple entities

Tags: feast

is it possible to combine values from multiple entities in a feature? For example, each row of input data contains multiple people, each of which is an entity in the store. I want a feature that is the MAX of the supplied people values.
Is this possible?

I have read the docs on the on demand feature views, but it is not clear if I can combine data from different entities.